# useradd user with group with same uid and gid

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, users

I want to add a user named "nexus" with uid as 1234567 (example number) and gid 1234567.

I'm running the following command:

```
sudo useradd -r -U -u 1234567 -g 1234567 -m -c "nexus role account" -d /sonatype-work -s /bin/false nexus
```

But I get the error:

```
useradd: group '1234567' does not exist
```

And if I do:

```
sudo useradd -r -U -u 1234567 -m -c "nexus role account" -d /sonatype-work -s /bin/false nexus
```

Then when I check `id -u nexus` it shows the correct `uid` (1234567) but when I check `id -g nexus` the `gid` is set to `999`.

If I do `sudo adduser --uid 1234567 nexus` then the user and group ids are set the same.

Can I do the same with `useradd` or do I have to use `adduser` to achieve my goal?

I've been following this tutorial btw:

http://www.tecmint.com/add-users-in-linux/

P.S.: If I have to use `adduser` then can I do it without any human interaction; i.e.: automate the user creation via script?

EDIT:

This is the outcome of `sudo adduser --uid 1234567 nexus`

```
Adding user `nexus' ...
Adding new group `nexus' (1234567) ...
Adding new user `nexus' (1234567) with group `nexus' ...
The home directory `/home/nexus' already exists.  Not copying from `/etc/skel'.
adduser: Warning: The home directory `/home/nexus' does not belong to the user you are currently creating.
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
No password supplied
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
No password supplied
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
No password supplied
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged
Try again? [y/N] n
Changing the user information for nexus
Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default
    Full Name []: Nexus
    Room Number []: 
    Work Phone []: 
    Home Phone []: 
    Other []: 
Is the information correct? [Y/n] y
```

Comment: I think you need to do a `groupadd` first if you want to create a user with SPECIFIC uid AND gid.

Comment: I thought the ```-U``` would do that for me.. :S

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to Tom Yan, I've ended up solving my issue by creating a group with the same name then added the user to that group. So I did the following:

```
sudo groupadd -r -g 1234567 nexus \
  && sudo useradd -r -u 1234567 -g 1234567 -m -c "nexus role account" -d /sonatype-work -s /bin/false nexus
```

Answer (score 3):

Frankly,
I think it's a bug(feature). The documentation indicates that you can use the '-U' option to simultaneously create the user and group at the same time. Intuitively you would think that in such a case, it would take the value from the '-g' flag and create the group accordingly.

```
[root@centos4]# useradd -U -u 200 -g 200 -m -d /home/ansible -s /usr/bin/bash ansible
useradd: group '200' does not exist
```

The example above is similar to your useradd command. However, if I simply remove the '-g 200' argument it works immediately. Although unfortunately it seems that the gid is allocated with the standard method.

```
[root@centos4]# useradd -U -u 200 -m -d /home/ansible -s /usr/bin/bash ansible
[root@centos4]# egrep ansible /etc/passwd
ansible:x:200:1000::/home/ansible:/usr/bin/bash
[root@centos4]# egrep ansible /etc/group
ansible:x:1000:
```

The answer to your question is that if you want to add user and group at the same time you have to remove the -g option. It's not as elegant as both you and I hoped, but its better than nothing.

Hope that helps.
Take Care.